# Repository to download jsf 2 for maven 2

Tags: maven

I am trying to download the jsf-api.jar and jsf-Impl.jar in maven 2. I tried using the following repository but couldn't able to download from the repository. I am new to this maven tool, help me to resolve this.

```
        <repository>
            <id>jsf</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/2.0.3-SNAPSHOT</url>
        </repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repository url should look like:

```
    <repository>
        <id>jsf</id>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    </repository>
```

groupId, artifactId and version number are appended automatically appended to the URL when resolving.